# Securing GCP compute instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firewall

I've a Linux (ubuntu) instance running on google cloud platform .I've created this instance just for learning purpose.  It is hosting a website using NodeJS server listing on port 80.The  website  is serving a simple webpage . In firewall setting, I've allowed all HTTP/HTTPS traffic  and also all inbound traffic is allowed (All IPs allowed)  . Further to connect to my GUI base ubuntu I used NoMachine utility software ,which uses port 4000 (NX protocol).
I got an email from google stating

> Resources associated with your project Stream Project (id:
> XXXXXXXXXXXXX) are being suspended for cryptocurrency mining in
> violation of our Terms of Service.

After further enquiry they responded me with this email.

> We've detected that your Google Cloud Project Stream Project (id:
> XXXXXXXXX) IP  appears to be performing intrusion attempts
> against a third party.

My password of compute instance were weak (like "someting123") as I just wanted to use it for learning purpose . Now google notified tat they will suspend my account if don't take necessary security steps .
How do I secure my GCP? I  only want to use it to  serve my website and create OpenVPN serer for my private use.
I cannot configure firewall to  grant IP specific access to my compute instance as I don't have a static ip to connect to my instance .
Please suggest how can I secure my  Instance .

Comment: Perhaps IAP could be a [solution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qDfNErg2i_s)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to follow this public information guide which contains best practices to have the instances more secure.

Option 1: Review the host key values

You can use the gcloud command-line tool to verify that SSH keys are written to guest attributes:

```
gcloud compute instances get-guest-attributes VM_NAME \
  --query-path="hostkeys/" \
  --zone=ZONE
```

Replace the following:

```
VM_NAME: the name of the VM
ZONE: the name of the zone in which the VM is located
```

Option 2: Review the serial port

```
View the serial port output.
Select serial port 1.
```

[click here](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/connecting-securely) for more documentation.